# How can I get my turtle to pull liquid from a tank?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I've tried turtle.place() with a bucket selected, which I assume would emulate a right-click, but it didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: If you choose Squirtle, you will have a turtle who is a tank and shoots _out_ liquid. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a normal turtle will, however, Thermal Expansion adds a bucket turtle.  http://thermalexpansion.wikispaces.com/Bucket+Turtle

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MiscPeripherals bucket turtle for older Minecraft versions. Get it [here](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/4587-cc153mc152-miscperipherals-33/). For newer versions, use mods like Peripherals++
 to help you.

[Peripherals++ Bucket Turtle wiki page.](https://github.com/austinv11/PeripheralsPlusPlus/wiki/Thirsty-Turtle-Upgrade)